# WPF touchscreen events not working properly

Tags: wpf, events, touchscreen

I've created a WPF touchscreen application at work.

When I use a mouse, it behaves as you would expect. However, when using the touchscreen it doesn't behave as it should. It will regularly lag on a PreviewMouseDown touch event, and sometimes won't actually respond at all. Other times it works fine.

Does anybody know what could cause this behaviour, and what can I do to resolve it?

Many thanks

Comment: what version of wpf?  there were a lot of touch improvements in wpf in .net 4.6.1 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2015/10/29/wpf-in-net-4-6-1/

Comment: I'm definitely having the same issue....net 4.6.1 doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In researching the issue for someone over at EE, I ran across [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b5f4c8ae-2d9f-49f0-bec2-604c45999aac/wpfpreviewtouchdown-and-previewmousedown-behavior-is-quite-annoying). Essentially, the PreviewTouchDown event does not occur until a finger touches the screen and moves. The answering post author goes on to say

> To cause the **PreviewTouchDown** event to occur as soon as a finger touches the screen, set the **Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled** attached property to **false** for this element.

This solution was posted in early 2014 and hasn't been rebutted, so it *should* work.